# GCC for google app engine

Tags: c, google-app-engine, gcc, clang

We have a application(`native c/c++` library) which is compiled based on user requirements and system configuration, currently we compile the library with gcc and response it synchronously or asynchronously to the user, but it's happening localy.
Now we have integrated the web part with app engine for now.
**Question**
How may I have GCC or clang compiler on my google app engine profile? is it possible? or I shall think about a dedicated server?

Comment: You can't run any thing other than java, php or pure python at the moment.  Very soon managed VM's will be available which will allow you appengine code to directly run native code on the VM instances.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thanks buddy :D, and by `soon` dear, how long is it? so soon? or...?

Comment: The managed VM are in limited access at the moment. You can sign up for it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate your GAE application with Compute engine. At the recent google cloud event, there were several demos on how to integrate between appengine and compute engine. This may be a good [starting point](https://cloud.google.com/events/google-cloud-platform-live/). Or look for [a good sample on github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-google-compute-engine-orchestrator) on how to integrate compute engine and app engine.

Comment: Thanks buddy :D, and with cloud computing, do I have completely OS root access?